# Can't convert string time in moment to correct format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Hey I have a react app where I made a slider for time. the time is for example: `3 PM` or `7:30 AM` like this format.

But I can't seem to format it correctly using moment, it is always returning AM
Here is my implementation:

```
moment(dropoffTime.formattedTime, ['h:mm A'])
          .locale('en')
          .format('hh:mm A')
```

Comment: what does `dropoffTime.formattedTime` look like

Comment: like the example I mentioned in the first two lines `7:30 AM`

Answer (score 0):

.format working fine and giving PM for me right now. Maybe you can console.log dropoffTime.formattedTime in order to see what is the value before formatting

```js
console.log(moment(new Date())
          .locale('en')
          .format('hh:mm A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`moment` accepts dates either as a `Date` object or in a string format:

```js
const dropoffTime = new Date();

const str = moment(dropoffTime)
          .locale('en')
          .format('hh:mm A');
          
console.log(str)
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",function(){
  console.log(moment(this.value, ['h:mm A']).locale('en').format('hh:mm A'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" value="12:34" >
```